# How do I manually control the style of ListBoxItem completely in Windows Phone7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I met a very strange problem recently.

I want to control the ListBoxItem's render by myself for a very complicated ListBox,
when i finish the work , I found that the first appearance is exactly what i wanna, but when i scroll down the ListBox, I was confused and frustrated to see the orders of ListBoxItem is not in order at all.

Now I created a new empty similiar project and tested ,the result is same.( In Windows Phone 7 is , But in WPF application everything is well.)

V1:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTest">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}" Width="1000"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

V1 is just binding the property to special control, in this way ,everything is well .
and things are different in V2:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTest">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:TestPanel Data="{Binding}"  HoldedHeight="100"></local:TestPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and the TestPanel in DataTemplate is :

```
public class TestPanel : StackPanel
{
    private bool _beginLoaded;
    private bool _isLoaded;
    private ListBox _parentListBox;

    public TestPanel()
        : base()
    {
        this.Loaded += TestPanel_Loaded;
    }

    void TestPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Data != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ProgramsPanel_Loaded with {0}", Data.Channel);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ProgramsPanel_Loaded with NULL data");
        }

        if (_beginLoaded || _isLoaded)
            return;

        _beginLoaded = true;
        InitializeWidthParent();
        this.Children.Clear();
        Show(Data, HoldedWidth, HoldedHeight);
        _isLoaded = true;
    }




    private void InitializeWidthParent()
    {
        _parentListBox = FindParent<listbox>(this);
        if (_parentListBox != null)
        {
            HoldedWidth = _parentListBox.ActualWidth;               
        }
    }

    static T FindParent<t>(DependencyObject d) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent = d;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            if (parent != null && (parent.GetType() == typeof(T)))
            {
                return parent as T;
            }
        }
        return parent as T;
    }

    private void Show(TestDataItem data, double holdedwidth, double holdedheight)
    {

        if (data == null)
            return;

        if (!holdedwidth.IsValid() || !holdedheight.IsValid())
            return;

        #region Stand at Left Side (Channel Name and Image)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Begin Show this Pannel of {0}", data.Channel);

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { FontSize = 32,  Height=HoldedHeight,Text = data.Channel, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };


        this.Children.Add(tb);
        #endregion

        #region Right Side


        #endregion
    }

    public double HoldedWidth
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double HoldedHeight
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Data" /> dependency property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string DataPropertyName = "Data";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="Data" />
    /// property. This is a dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public TestDataItem Data
    {
        get
        {
            return (TestDataItem)GetValue(DataProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DataProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="Data" /> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        DataPropertyName,
        typeof(TestDataItem),
        typeof(TestPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDataPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnDataPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as TestPanel).OnDataPropertyChanged(e.OldValue as TestDataItem, e.NewValue as TestDataItem);
    }

    protected virtual void **OnDataPropertyChanged**(TestDataItem oldData, TestDataItem newData)
    {
        if (oldData != null)
        {
            Show(oldData, HoldedWidth, HoldedHeight);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("rebuild old pannel of {0}, ListBox count is {1}", oldData.Channel, _parentListBox.Items.Count);
        }

        string oldstr = oldData == null ? "NULL" : oldData.Channel;
        string newstr = newData == null ? "NULL" : newData.Channel;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("old data is {0}, new data is {1}", oldstr, newstr);
    }
}


public static partial class Extentsions
{
    public static bool IsValid(this double width)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(width)
            || Math.Abs(width) < 0.1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}


public class TestDataItem
{
    public string Channel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

the main page is :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);         
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<testdataitem> source = new ObservableCollection<testdataitem>();
        ListBoxTest.ItemsSource = source;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            source.Add(new TestDataItem() { Channel = i.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

so why after I use V2 the ListBoxItems will disorderly appear , and how could I solve this problem?

PS: the output information is:

```
old data is NULL, new data is 0

old data is NULL, new data is 1

old data is NULL, new data is 2

old data is NULL, new data is 3

old data is NULL, new data is 4

old data is NULL, new data is 5

old data is NULL, new data is 6

old data is NULL, new data is 7

old data is NULL, new data is 8

old data is NULL, new data is 9

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 0

Begin Show this Pannel of 0

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 1

Begin Show this Pannel of 1

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 2

Begin Show this Pannel of 2

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 3

Begin Show this Pannel of 3

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 4

Begin Show this Pannel of 4

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 5

Begin Show this Pannel of 5

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 6

Begin Show this Pannel of 6

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 7

Begin Show this Pannel of 7

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 8

Begin Show this Pannel of 8

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 9

Begin Show this Pannel of 9

Begin Show this Pannel of 9

rebuild old pannel of 9, ListBox count is 10

old data is 9, new data is 0

ProgramsPanel_Loaded with 8
```

Thanks,
Sparkling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is caused by the "feature" of listbox: [UI Virtualization](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2009/09/06/ui-virtualization-vs-data-virtualization.aspx). 
Simply speaking, UI Virtualization will help you reduce the UI memory and only render the elements visible on the screen.
So your custom testpanel will be recycled and reused when you scroll the listbox. 
May be I am not cleared, but you can just try to disable the UI Virtualization feature of the listbox by using stackpanel as the ListBox's ItemPanel to see if your problem is resolved.

You can define your listbox's ItemsPanelTemplate like this:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Also you can add a propertychangedCallback to your Data Property, and rebuild your panel element in this callback. This will call when your panel is recycled and its Data is changed.

```
/// <summary>
/// Identifies the <see cref="Data" /> dependency property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    DataPropertyName,
    typeof(TestDataItem),
    typeof(TestPanel),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnIsDataChanged));

protected static void OnIsDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //rebuild your panel here......

        this.Children.Clear();
        Show(Data, HoldedWidth, HoldedHeight);
    }
```

Comment: yes , redefine the listbox's ItemsPanel can solve this problem, but will cause performance burden. And why the V1's xaml doesn't have this problem and V2's xaml has. Both of them have the feature of UI virtualizaiton

Comment: If your list conatins lots of items, yes, it will cause performance issue. You can also make some modification on your custom testpanel, add a propertyChangedCallback to your DataProperty, and when your panel is recycled, the Data changes too, you can rebuild your panel in the callback

Comment: I add call back in my code above, but it seems the appearance of the listbox is still disorder.

Comment: Why do you put Show(oldData) in the callback, in my opinion, it should be Show(newData) to show the correct current data. I hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: I test the Show(newData) too, the result is almost same. I also print some output information at the end of this question.

Comment: I just find your answer is changed . It seems the problem is solved in your method. I will test it again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tested several times just now. The problem is completely solved.No performance issue and appearance issue. Thanks again!

Comment: And I also test your code Seconds ago, I found it's your Loaded handler. Your _beginload and _isloaded flag were not reset when your panel is recycled and reused, so it will never call your clear() and show(Data) function in loaded handler.

Comment: Did you mean i should reset _beginload and isloaded flag in the UnLoaded handler?

Comment: If you choose build panel in your PropertyChangedCallback like my answer, you could just leave those flag as not reset. If you want to keep in your way like creating panel children in load handler, you may need reset those flags in Unloaded handler or the PropertyChangedCallback. I think both two should work as the same.

Comment: yes, the flags in the Loaded handler is not necessary at all. it is the root of evil...

Comment: I tested again and again, rebuild the panel has a little performance issue(is not serious, but indeed exists), i don't know the reason because the panels rebuilt are only several ,not so many. Maybe I should get into the ListBox 's original DataTemplate binding.